# The X Button Won't Work On VBS

Tags: vbscript

So, as I was doing my coding runs that I do once in a while, I wanted to make a batch file since I was interested. I just found out something weird, the small X on the top right of vbs files somehow does not do its job. Heres my code so far:

```
    Dim Msg, Style, Title, Ctxt, Response
        Msg = "Do you want to continue?"    ' Define message.
        Style = vbYesNo  + vbCritical  ' Define buttons.
        Title = "MsgBox Demonstration"    ' Define title.
        Ctxt = 1000
    Response = MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title, Help, Ctxt)
    If Response = vbYes Then
        Msg = "Hello, How Are You Doing?"
        Style = vbYesNo + vbInformation
        Ctxt = 1000
        Response = MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title, Help, Ctxt)
        If Response = vbYes Then
        Else
        Wscript.quit
        End If
    Else
        CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "speak.vbs"
    End If
```

Just a note, the reason why I restated everything is because I have two VBS files in just one code. By the way, I do not mean the no or cancel button, i mean the exit button, or the little X with a red border around it located at the top left of all programs. Thanks for Helping!

Comment: Could you tell us exactly what you are expecting the "X" to do, and what it actually does in your script? It is not designed to exit the script, only close the MsgBox itself...

Comment: Top right of all programs, not top left?  Depending on how your windows theme is configured I guess.

Comment: So then, I am currently running Windows Vista Service Pack 2, with Home Basic. As usual, the graphics are only a little upgraded from XP, so every bar in the top right is all the usual default bar just like for Windows XP and Windows 7 users. I am just wondering, is there a way to configure the red default "X" somehow, because even configuring the  normal Cancel button doesn't make the red X work.

Comment: Oh, whoops, I mean the top right, whoops. Thx for clarifying!